# Sending a file to Mattermost through Standard API

Tags: node.js

I am trying to upload a file to a locally hosted mattermost server, and I am totally lost in the example provided here : https://api.mattermost.com/#tag/files. I am using node.js on my end , and here is my code.

I have referred to a couple of posts on SO, and while some recommend attaching the data in the form field, I am not sure I have figured out how to do that. Some posts also suggest that pass the parameters such as name of the file as a query, which I have tried but have not been able to upload the file.

```
console.log("This is what the url looks like " + url);
let options = getDefaultOptions(url, "POST");
var imageURL = 'xyz.png';
  var dataString = `{"channel_id":`${channel}`, "filename": `${imageURL}`};
  options.body = dataString;request(options, function (error, response, 
body) 
  {
      if( error )
          {
              console.log( chalk.red( error ));
              return; // Terminate execution.
          }
      console.debug( response );
      return body;

  });
```

This is the error message

```
body: '{"id":"api.context.invalid_body_param.app_error","message":"Invalid or missing post in request body","detailed_error":"","request_id":"ndcgx7yqetbg387ek45hztpg3r","status_code":400}' }
```

Comment: Your `dataString` have format issue I think so.

Comment: @Subburaj, formatting error on my part ! Corrected. But this does not solve the problem.

Comment: now what's the error you r getting??

Comment: What I meant to say was that the mistake was in pasting the code onto SO, but the actual code is in fact correct.

Comment: what's the problem in pasting the code?? So after you changed your dataString format its worked correctly??

Answer (score 0):

Your dataString should be a valid json as below:

```
{
    "channel_id": "${channel}",
    "filename": "${imageURL}"
}
```